# I can't make the loop

Tags: c++

In this code I'm trying to take data from a file line by line ..

### File

> 2
>   Mohab
>   20
>   male
>   mohab@server.com
>   Cairo

### Code

```
bool Employee::login(int ID, string username)
{
    int line1, i;
    string line;
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Employee.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (myfile >> line1)
        {
            if (ID == line1)
            {
                for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    myfile >> line;
                    if (line == username)
                    {
                        return true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }
            else    
                continue;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else 
    { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I managed to loop from the 2nd line to the last one. If the file content has more than 1 person info where to put the loop and how to make `line1` variable check all the lines in the file ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: is your input well-formed?

if so, just do it all in the condition: `while (file >> id >> name >> age >> sex...)`.

Comment: then the next iteration of the loop will pick up the next employee

Comment: if I did that , then what if add more info ? , will i keep going : while ( myfile >> id >> name >> age >> sex >> newdata >> newdata ...)

Comment: well if this isn't for a class, you should be placing this info in XML format and using one of the copious C++ XML parsers that will take care of all this for you and return objects, which is how the Employee object should be designed anyway, but i don't know how far you want to take this program...

Comment: basically, there is always a better way, but it may not be worth the extra cost associated with doing it the right way

Comment: it's for a class actually .. and i'll think about the XML format

Comment: no problem, and kudos to you for wondering about flexibility of the design for a class project

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf absolutely, and a much less bloated option for his simple use case.